# Scala: seq.size vs pattern matching

Tags: scala, if-statement, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have to make a decision based on size of a Seq.

So, either I can do:

```
if(mySeq.size() > 0) // do your stuff
```

Or, I can do:

```
mySeq match {
  case x :: _ => // do your stuff
}
```

Which one should I prefer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Seq` is an abstraction of the underlying collection type. This presents a few problems.

`case x :: _ =>` won't work unless the underlying collection is a `List`, but you can change it to `case x +: _ =>` for more universal coverage.

`mySeq.size` might be reasonably efficient if the underlying collection is something like a `Vector` but it's a linear operation on a `List`.

My recommendation would be to use `mySeq.sizeIs > 0` (Scala 2.13). `sizeIs` is designed to terminate as soon as the comparison can be determined, so even on a `List` it should return `true` after traversing only one element.

Answer (score 6):

If your checking are exactly the size > 0 or not, I prefer to

```
if (mySeq.nonEmpty) { .. }
```

This solution without performance losing and works for all version of scala. In my opinion `nonEmpty`  is more intuitive than size checking.